# Получить информацию о томах

Tags: c++, файловая-система

Как узнать, существует тот или другой том? Например, мне нужно сделать так:

- если существует диск **D**, то создать файлы там;
- если нет, то создать файлы на диске **C**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - просто попробовать создать нужный файл (предварительно проверив его существование - чтоб чего не затереть случайно...)

Иначе надо использовать средства конкретной операционной системы, потому что в самом C++ такого понятия как том просто нет. Как нет его и в ряде операционных систем :)

Вот как это [рекомендуется](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1e5zwe0c.aspx) делать в Windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <direct.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <ctype.h>  

int main( void )  
{  
   int drive, curdrive;
   static char path[_MAX_PATH];  

   // Save current drive.  
   curdrive = _getdrive();  

   printf( "Available drives are:\n" );  

   // If we can switch to the drive, it exists.  
   for( drive = 1; drive <= 26; drive++ )  
   {  
      if( !_chdrive( drive ) )  
      {  
         printf( "%c:", drive + 'A' - 1 );  
         if( _getdcwd( drive, path, _MAX_PATH ) != NULL )  
            printf( " (Current directory is %s)", path );  
         putchar( '\n' );  
      }  
   }  

   // Restore original drive.  
   _chdrive( curdrive );  
}
```

Comment: Ну это да) А есть ли другие способы?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Имея поддержку c++17 (или даже c++14 с экспериментальной частью) можно использовать [следующий код](http://rextester.com/TNYWH67732) для проверки наличия того или иного диска, основанный на библиотеке [`filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    for( char drive = 'a'; drive <= 'z'; ++drive ) 
    {
        fs::path p = std::string(1, drive) + ":";
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << p << " - " << fs::exists(p) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень гуманный способ:

```
int n;
char dd[4];

DWORD dr = GetLogicalDrives();

for( int i = 0; i < 26; i++ )
{
    n = ((dr>>i)&0x00000001);

    if( n == 1 ){
        dd[0] = char(65+i); dd[1] = ':'; dd[2] = '\\'; dd[3] = 0;

        cout << "Available disk drives : " << dd << endl;
    }
}
```